# How to get multiple XMLHttpRequests to occur serially?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code, which works (sort of).  When I run it, the page displays information about the two coins, but returns 'undefined' for the coin price.  The call to alert() indicates that the getCoinPrice function is running AFTER the main code.  How do you execute the code so that the function call happens serially?  If that's not possible, would it be better to learn to use the Fetch API?

Here's the code, in its entirety:

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>Use the XMLHttpRequest to get the content of a file.</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function getCoinPrice(id) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var URL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/" + id + "/";

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var Obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var price = Obj.data.quotes.USD.price;

        alert(price);
        return(price);
    }
  }

  xhr.open("GET", URL, true);
  xhr.send();
}

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var coins = [ "BTC","ETH" ]

        for(j=0; j < coins.length; j++) {
            for(i=0; i < myObj.data.length; i++) {
                if (myObj.data[i].symbol == coins[j]) {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += 
                    myObj.data[i].id + "," + myObj.data[i].name + "," +
                    myObj.data[i].symbol + "," +
                    getCoinPrice( myObj.data[i].id ) + "<br>" ;
                }
            }

        }
    }
};

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/", true);
  xmlhttp.send();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean synchronously?  Learning the fetch api and leaving ajax in the past would probably be for the best.

Comment: Yes. That's it in a nutshell.